# Union All with a particular value at first row

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-order-by

I'm using union all clause like

```
select * from products where id=1 
union select * from products order by price desc
```

But as result i got the product with **id 1** at the middle of the list as it makes a **filter with price**

How can i get the product with **id 1** at the first row?

Comment: `select * from products order by case id when 1 then 0 else 1 end, price desc`

Comment: `order by` applies to the union as a whole, not to the last select.  the order of the selects that make up the union isn't guaranteed to have any effect on the actual output order.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a conditional sort rather than `union`:

```
select *
from products
order by case when id = 1 then 1 else 2 end, price desc
```

This puts first the row with id 1, followed by the rest of the records ordered by decreasing price.